# Simple Xml list parsing problem

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I have this xml:

```
<root>
<fruitlist>
    <apple>4</apple>
    <apple>5</apple>
    <orange>2</orange>
    <orange>6</orange>
</fruitlist>
</root>
```

I'm writing a parser class, although I can't figure out how to deal with multiple node types. I can easily parse a list that contains only one node type (eg. just apples, not oranges)

```
@ElementList(name = "fruitlist")
private List<Apple> exercises;
```

with more than one node type it also wants so parse non Apple nodes which doesn't work.
I also tried to make another list for oranges, but it doen't work, I can't use fruitlist name more than once.

```
@ElementList(name = "fruitlist", entry = "orange")
private List<Orange> exercises;
```

The ideal would be two seperate list for both node types.

Hubi

EDIT:
After more searching & fiddling this question is a duplicate:

[Inheritance with Simple XML Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6846904/197255)

Comment: Can't you just make `List<Fruit>` and have the Apple and Orange class extend from the Fruit base class / interface?

Comment: I've also tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: Something like this:

class Fruit...

class Apple extends Fruit ...

class Orange extends Fruit...


@ElementList(name = "fruitlist")
private List<Fruit> exercises;

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work.

```
@ElementListUnion({
   @ElementList(entry="apple", type=Apple.class),
   @ElementList(entry="orange", type=Orange.class)
})
private List<Fruit> fruitlist;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal data structure to solve this parsing problem would probably be an [HashTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) with the name of the element as key (String) and the list of his possible child as content (List

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> numbers = new Hashtable<String, List<String>>();
```

Anyway if you wanna parse an XML file there are lots of possible framworks you can use in Java.

Comment: I didn't mention in the original post, because it is not seriously related but I would like use parsing on android. On android jaxb is not supported and I wanted to avoid using dom or sax parsing.